# Usage of async methods in isolated task

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, .net-4.5

I have an asynchronous method that does something peculiar (at least, looks peculiar to me):

```
public async ReturnType MethodNameHere()
{
    var result = await DoSomethingAsync(); // this could take a while (dozens of seconds)!
    // no other processing after awaiting the result of the asynchronous task
    return result;
}
```

This method is consumed by another method, as follows (meant to run in an infinite loop):

```
private async void ProcessSomething()
{
    // some console printing
    var returnType = await MethodNameHere();

    // do some _actual_ work here, process stuff, etc

    ProcessSomething(); // call the same method again
}
```

Now this task is running via `Task.Factory.StartNew(ProcessSomething, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)`, which, along with other tasks that do similar work, are combined with `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll`.

**Question**

Is it correct to assume that, if the scheduler ends up putting each task on the same thread as one another, the tasks will not block each other?

If that is the case, is there even *any* benefit to calling the asynchronous version of `DoSomething` if it is to be running "alone" in a `Task`?

Comment: It sounds like you may be misunderstanding async.  Is your work CPU-bound?

Comment: Nope, not CPU-bound. The work is essentially listening to many queues (possibly timing out for dozens of seconds). I don't want the queue processing to block one another while timed out, hence why I looked into using `async` (which might turn out to be a bad idea).

Comment: Then you want `async` combined with `await Task.WhenAll()`

Comment: Let me make sure I understand you: if I have one of these `async` methods for each queue (mind you, these methods can wait for a bit until it hits the timeout limit and returns from the async method), all I have to do is that code you wrote? It won't block one queue while another is 'waiting'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do some work before the async operation finishes, just do that work before `await`ing the returned `Task`.

However, the primary purpose of async operations is to avoid consuming threads while waiting for non-blocking operations.